# How to debug Javascript code of a Windows Phone 8.1 app with SAML and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, debugging

How can I debug a `javascript` file that is included in the `HTML` file of a `webview`? The HTML file is navigated through the `C#` code behind the `webview`.

With Visual Studio 13 I tried by setting some breakpoints, but the debugger doesn't reach the breakpoints in the javascript file though that lines actually executes perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [WEb INspector REmote](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Home.html)? Unfortunately this will not give you access to breakpoints, but will enable you to get console logging.

Comment: That tool works for Apache Cordova based applications. But in my case I need to test the a single webview(the app contains other pages).